# Elasticsearch 5 and Nest 5: Scroll Issue

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm using Elasticsearch 5.1.1 and Nest 5.0 and I'm trying to search items by query and after that to delete these items.

This is the code:

```
var searchDescriptor = new SearchDescriptor()
.Index(indexName)
.Size(itemsPerShard)
.StoredFields((Field)"Id")
.Scroll("1m")
.Sort(ss => ss.Ascending(SortSpecialField.DocumentIndexOrder))
.Query(qd => qd
.QueryString(snd => snd
.Query(deleteByQuery)
.DefaultOperator(Operator.And))
);
var scanResults = client.Search(s => searchDescriptor);
var results = client.Scroll("1m", scanResults.ScrollId);
```

When itemsPerShard > 10.000, I receive this error:
{Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful low level call on POST: /index/_search?scroll=1m}.
And in elasticsearch log file:
Batch size is too large, size must be less than or equal to: [10000] but was [10001]. Scroll batch sizes cost as much memory as result windows so they are controlled by the [index.max_result_window] index level setting.

This code works in with Nest 1.X.

Thank you!

Comment: Scroll batch size has been limited in ES 5.x [Have a look](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/19249).

Comment: The error message tells you the exact problem and the setting that controls the size: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html#dynamic-index-settings